# Maven lint tool

Tags: maven

I have been working configuring a number of projects for use with Maven.

Most projects contains multiple modules (POMs) and these are all based on a few POMs I pulled from another project.

While the structure is generally fine, there are a number of redundant elements included in some files.

Is there a tool that I can use to scan for elements that are duplicates, not ever referenced, should be moved up a level etc.

I have been looking at [Maven POM Lint Plugin](https://www.coveros.com/maven-pom-lint-plugin/), which looks like it might do the job. Is there anything else I should be considering?

Answer (score 3):

[Maven POM Lint Plugin](https://www.coveros.com/maven-pom-lint-plugin/) can help you a bit in maintaining your POMs to be clean and short. For me however, what is usually far more important, is to manage declared dependencies right. I like to have only those dependencies declared that are really used and also I like to explicitly depend on what I use without getting stuff transitively. For these things I recommend [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) with its [dependency:analyze](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) goal.